# How to know last log before every event? R language

Tags: r

Here is my table:

```
user_id    event       timestamp
Rob        business    111111
Rob        progress    111112
Rob        business    222222
Mike       progress    111111
Mike       progress    222222
Rob        progress    000001
Mike       business    333333
Mike       progress    444444
Lee        progress    111111
Lee        progress    222222
Mike       business    333334
```

Dput table:

```
    dput(input)
    df <- structure(list(user_id = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L),
 .Label = c("Lee", "Mike", "Rob"), class = "factor"), 
 event = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L),
 .Label = c("business", "progress"), class = "factor"), 
timestamp = c(111111,111112, 222222, 111111, 222222, 1, 333333, 444444, 111111, 222222, 333334)), 
.Names = c("user_id", "event", "timestamp"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to know last `progress` event before every `business` event happens for every `user_id` (output):

```
    user_id    event       timestamp
    Mike       progress    222222
    Mike       progress    222222
    Rob        progress    111112
    Rob        progress         1
```

Thx for help!

Comment: How did second row got included in the expected output?

Comment: @RonakShah Sorry It was a mistake

Comment: @Hack-R Yeah sorry

Comment: @Smasell No worries, I have the correct result in my answer. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @Hack-R I mean for every user_id. Mike has business with timestamp 333333 and progress with timestamp 222222.

Comment: @Smasell But Rob's progress is more recent than Mike's for the business event 333333. You're saying you want every progress event prior to the business event, not just the most recent one?

Comment: @Hack-R For every user_id separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as I'm understanding the problem correctly, this looks like it could be solved with some use of the `lag` function and `dplyr`.

Here's an example:

```
# Set up the data structure
df <- structure(list(user_id = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Lee", "Mike", "Rob"), class = "factor"), 
    event = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("business", 
    "progress"), class = "factor"), timestamp = c(111111,111112, 222222, 
    111111, 222222, 1, 333333, 444444, 111111, 222222)), .Names = c("user_id", 
    "event", "timestamp"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

# Perform the manipulation
df %>% 
    arrange(user_id, timestamp) %>% # Sort by user and timestamp
    group_by(user_id) %>% # Group/partition by each user
    mutate(last_event = lag(event, 1), # Find the last event
           last_timestamp = lag(timestamp, 1)) %>% # And the time it occurred
    filter(event == "business") %>% # Chop down to just the business events - as that's what we're interested in
    select(user_id, last_event, last_timestamp) %>% # Select the fields of interest
    rename(event = last_event, # Tidy up the field names
           timestamp = last_timestamp)
```

> ```
>   user_id    event timestamp
>    <fctr>   <fctr>     <dbl>
> 1    Mike progress    222222
> 2     Rob progress         1
> 3     Rob progress    111112
> ```

This approach will not work if the event preceding each `business` event is *not* progress, however. A simple fix is just to filter down to `business` and `progress` events only, though:

```
df %>% 
    filter(event == "business"|event == "progress") %>% 
    arrange(user_id, timestamp) %>% 
    group_by(user_id) %>% 
    mutate(last_event = lag(event, 1),
           last_timestamp = lag(timestamp, 1)) %>% 
    filter(event == "business") %>% 
    select(user_id, last_event, last_timestamp) %>% 
    rename(event = last_event, 
           timestamp = last_timestamp)
```

On this data set the output will be the same, but if other events creep in this might be a necessary step.

Comment: Thx it works but I faced the problem if I have 2 business events in a row I have business event in my result! How can I fix it?

Comment: You could use some similar logic with `lead` and/or `lag` and the `row_number()` function to identify `business` events occurring one after the other.

You could then chop out one or more `business` events that were sequential until.

Alternatively, you could expand the `lag` logic to simply find the most recent `progress` event before _any_ `business` event (even sequential ones). It depends on whether you're interested in `progress` events directly before `business` events, or just the most recent `progress` event before each `business` event.

Comment: I'm interested in most recent progress event before each business event

Comment: If you mock up some sample data I can think of a way to do this with a simple join.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <-
structure(list(user_id = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Lee", "Mike", "Rob"), class = "factor"), 
event = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("business", 
"progress"), class = "factor"), timestamp = c(111111,111112, 222222, 
111111, 222222, 1, 333333, 444444, 111111, 222222)), .Names = c("user_id", 
"event", "timestamp"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

#I want to know last progress event before every business event happens

new <- df[0,]  
for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
  if(df$event[i] == "business" & df$event[i-1] == "progress"){
   new <- rbind(new, df[i-1,]) 
  }
}  
new
```

> ```
>   user_id    event timestamp
> 2     Rob progress    111112
> 6     Rob progress         1
> ```

Note there are only 2 rows in the result because `business` only appeared three times and the first time it appeared it was in the first row.

Comment: But where is Mike?

Comment: @Smasell Mike isn't supposed to be in the result. Mike never had progress right before business. Double check your example and let me know a row number if you're still confused. Mike had `progress` but never `progress` right before `business`.

Comment: Sorry!  Use timestamp to know order for every user_id

Comment: @Smasell No problem. I'm not sure I understand your comment though. Do you understand why this result is correct now? It captures the last `progress` event row before each `business` event row, like you requested.

Comment: @Hack-R The OP has updated the question again. I am not sure on what condition he wants the result. Anyways, for now I have deleted my answer.

Comment: This is not the correct outpu as per the OP's new data